# How to get radio button pop up when two date pickers have same date?

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-radiobutton

I am working on a simple app in which i have taken two date pickers they subtract two dates and display the result. But i want that if the two dates are same like 06/04/2017 then two radio button should pop up for selecting full day and half day as soon as it calculates that the two dates are same.

how to do that?

```
    public class Leave extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView date;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
TextView date2;
//TextView setDay;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2;
TextView no_of_days;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave);

    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    //setDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setDay);
    no_of_days = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_of_days);

    // initiate the date picker and a button
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    // perform click event on edit text
    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Leave.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                            date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    // initiate the date picker and a button
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    // perform click event on edit text
    date2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(Leave.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                            date2.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog2.show();

        }
    });

    no_of_days.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            String date01 = date.getText().toString();
            String date02 = date2.getText().toString();
            try {
                Date d = format.parse(date01);
                Date d1 = format.parse(date02);
                getDifferenceDays(d, d1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.leave_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    SpinnerActivity() throws ParseException {
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
}



private void setupRadios() {
    RadioButton radio_full = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_full);
    RadioButton radio_Half = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_Half);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioleave);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            int buttonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (buttonId) {
                case R.id.radio_full:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected Full Day Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_Half:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected Half Day Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}

public void getDifferenceDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
    int daysdiff = 0;
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1;
    daysdiff = (int) diffDays;
    no_of_days.setText(Integer.toString(daysdiff));
    System.out.println("day count=>" + daysdiff);
}
```

}

Comment: plz guyz help me out

Comment: Do you want the radio buttons to pop up as soon as you select the dates from the date pickers ?

Comment: Yes. Look there are two condition if i select first date like 06/04/2017 and the second date is like 07/04/2017 it shows the result in the text view. but if both the dates are same like 06/07/2017 then the result will be 0 then this time radio button should pop up.

Comment: But the difference will be shown only when textview is clicked, so you will have to pop up radio buttons when the dates are selected

Comment: can we changed that too? means the date should be shown in text view automatically?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too

Comment: plz help me out for both the cases then.

Comment: Sure, I am working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the dates whenever any date is selected from any one of the date picker's as follows :

```
public class Leave extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView date;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
TextView date2;
//TextView setDay;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2;
TextView no_of_days;
String date1 = "", date2 = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leave);

    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    //setDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setDay);
    no_of_days = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_of_days);
    RadioButton radio_full = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_full);
    RadioButton radio_Half = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_Half);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioleave);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            int buttonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            switch (buttonId) {
                case R.id.radio_full:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected Full Day Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_Half:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected Half Day Leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    // initially hide the radio buttons
    radio_full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    radio_Half.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // initiate the date picker and a button
    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    // perform click event on edit text
    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Leave.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                            // assign the value to date1
                            date1 = dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;

                            date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            // check if date2 has been set and compare it with date1
                            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(date2)) {

                                // get difference
                                getDifferenceDays(date, date2);

                                if(date1.equals(date2)) {
                                    // pop up radio button
                                   radio_full.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                   radio_Half.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } else {
                                   // hide radio buttons
                                   radio_full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   radio_Half.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    // initiate the date picker and a button
    date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date2);
    // perform click event on edit text
    date2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calender class's instance and get current date , month and year from calender
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
            // date picker dialog
            datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(Leave.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text

                            // assign the value to date2
                            date2 = dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;

                            date2.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                            // check if date2 has been set and compare it with date1
                            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(date1)) {

                                // get difference
                                getDifferenceDays(date, date2);

                                if(date1.equals(date2)) {
                                   // pop up radio button
                                   radio_full.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                   radio_Half.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                } else {
                                   // hide radio buttons
                                   radio_full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   radio_Half.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }  
                            }

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog2.show();

        }
    });

    no_of_days.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
            String date01 = date.getText().toString();
            String date02 = date2.getText().toString();
            try {
                Date d = format.parse(date01);
                Date d1 = format.parse(date02);
                getDifferenceDays(d, d1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.leave_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: its showing code need java.lang.String and I have taken android.widget.TextView as soon as convert it to java.lang.String errors come.

Comment: Please post your error, you just need to make the changes as given in my answer

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable date1
 error: incompatible types: TextView cannot be converted to CharSequence
 error: cannot find symbol variable date1
 error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to TextView
 error: cannot find symbol variable date1
 error: cannot find symbol variable date1
 error: cannot find symbol method getDifferenceDays(Date,Date)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: after making changes these error came...........Error:(278, 38) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:(257, 14) error: cannot find symbol method setOnClickListener(<anonymous OnClickListener>)
Error:(306, 38) error: cannot find symbol method getText()
Error:(310, 21) error: cannot find symbol method getDifferenceDays(Date,Date)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Just rename your String type global variables from date1 to strDate1 and date2 to strDate2 respectively.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.nilesh.sackinfostaff, PID: 27066
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nilesh.sackinfostaff/com.example.nilesh.sackinfostaff.Leave}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please make sure that you have initialized your TextViews

Comment: thanks it helped me radio buttons are popping up now but the date difference it now showing in textView no_of_days not even by clicking and not even automatically. I want automatically.

Comment: Were you getting correct difference in dates through getDifferenceDays() method ?

Comment: I have called getDifferenceDays() method in onDateSet method within if condition for both datePicker dialogs

Comment: Sorry i am new to this field and that's y i am troubling u a lot. my companies email id is swtkrs@gmail.com please send me yours so i can contact you in near future.

Comment: Error:(241, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable date
Error:(289, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable date................................. and if i change it strdate it again shows error

Comment: Replace date with whatever TextView name you have used and date2 also

Comment: still not working. not getting ans automatically. want to remove onClickListener on no_of_Days so that i can get result directly on this (no_of_Days) text view

Comment: So, what is happening ?

Comment: ans is not displaying automatically in no_of_days textview. I want to get date diffrence in this text view

Comment: Try to log the values of both the dates and its difference too in getDifferenceDays() method

Comment: How? i didnt get what u said. dont understand technical words as i am new and still learning this.

Comment: where u have gone sir?